# windows Forms curve/plot control

Tags: winforms, qwt

I need plot a curve for my data , the source is like :

```
12, 14, 18, 30, ....
```

I was using Qt Qwt, and need port it to windows forms, are there controls? free of charge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the [Microsoft Chart controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en).